# Bootstrap add 'dot' at the end of a progress bar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to have a progress bar that has an output like this:

[image: Output]

Now, I currently have the following output:

[image: My output]

I have no idea why the tooltop is floating there, not above the current value tho...

Now this is my html;

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="48.5" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:48.5%">
        <span class="popOver" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="472 km"> </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here the CSS:

```
.progress {
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 9.5px;
    .progress-bar {
        background-color: #ec4124;
        border-radius: 5px;

        &[aria-valuenow]::after {
            content: "";
            width: 6px;
            height: 6px;
            position: absolute;
            border-radius: 100%;
            right: 7px;
            background-color: $white;
        }
    }
}

.tooltip{
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}

.tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
    background-color: $white;
    padding: 11px 16px;
    color: $red;
    font-family: Config, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-stretch: condensed;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 1.33;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 1;
}

.bs-tooltip-top .arrow::before, .bs-tooltip-auto[x-placement^=top] .arrow::before {
    top: 0;
    border-width: 0.4rem 0.4rem 0;
    border-top-color: #fff;
}
```

Does anyone know how I can have the tooltip at the correct value and a "white dot" at the current value?

**EDIT**

The dot is no more issue, I now have the tooltip-issue left.

Comment: It is because you give position: absolute CSS property along with right: 7px. and please use the editor snippet for the demonstration of your code. It will helpful for us.

Comment: Please create a snippet, So we are trying to help you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only need to make the progress-bar `position:relative`...

```
.progress {
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 9.5px;
    .progress-bar {
        background-color: #ec4124;
        border-radius: 5px;
        position: relative;

        &[aria-valuenow]::after {
            content: "";
            width: 6px;
            height: 6px;
            position: absolute;
            border-radius: 100%;
            right: 7px;
            background-color: $white;
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/3HFWuRTEH0

Comment: Okay, I figured that out haha, but now the next question is, how I can have the tooltip on the correct place :x

Comment: The original question has been answered. Please mark this answer accepted, and if you have another question (and there are no other similar questions) on SO, ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

Please check my demo on full page! I hope it's helpful for you.

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

```css
.row {
  padding: 4em 3em;
}

.textbox {
  height: 700px;
}

.progress {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.progress-bar {
  width: 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position:relative;
}
.progress-bar span[data-toggle="tooltip"]{
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: red;
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h3 class="bars">Scrollbars</h3>
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:25%;"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!"></span>      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```